# stdout.write() and input() in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, sys

I'm making a script that show you a question, you give the answer ("y" or "n") and the line is restarted, and appears another question. I've tried this (assuming that the number is the question)

```
import sys

for i in range (10):  
    sys.stdout.write('\r'+str(i))
    label = input()
    if label=='n':
        doSomething
    if label=='y':
        doSomethingElse
```

but in this cases, I get this

```
0n
1n
2y
3n
```

and I want that if I have

```
0
```

I give my answer and press Enter, the currently line disappear and the new number appears

```
1
```

and then I give an answer again, and so on.

I've already check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43150097/flush-output-in-for-loop-in-jupyter-notebook) question and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41888122/sys-stdout-flush-not-work-in-jupyter-notebook). I'm using python 3.5.

**Edit:**
Thanks to an answer, now I know that I need to avoid the '\n' of the input() function.

Comment: Have your defined input()?

Comment: no, input() is a function of python that wait for an input from the keyboard.

Comment: What we're your actual functions for "doSomething" and "doSomethingElse?"

Comment: They save in a file the answer with the question, but that's no relevant, because if a delete the last 4 lines, I still have the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `input()`,there always have a output with '\n'. This '\n' changed to a new line,then the '\r' can't work as you wanted.

So, Maybe you should break through here(the `input()`).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a `\n` like in (see `Part 1`) and you can use an `elif` (see `Part 2`)

```
for i in range (10):  
    sys.stdout.write(str(i) + '\n') # Part 1
    label = input()
    if label == 'n':
        doSomething
    elif label =='y':  # Part 2
        doSomething
```